# Compare date values between two files

Tags: shell-script, date

I have two files with dates:

**File1**

```
12/22/2017
```

**File2**

```
12/21/2017    
12/20/2017    
12/23/2017
```

File1 will only have one record. File2 will have multiple records. I need to check if any of the dates in file2 is greater than the date in file1. Date Format in both files will be `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Comment: *I need to check* - how it should be expressed? how should look the output?

Comment: If the condition is satisfied, then I need to echo  "Date in file2 is greater than file1"

Answer (score 2):

Here is small script which `sort`s both files, `grep`s for later dates than file1, and then counts (`wc -l`) if there are more than 1 `uniq` line (should be only 1 which comes from file1):

```
if [[ "$(sort -t/ -k3,3n -k1,1n -k2,2n file1 file2 | grep -A 1 -f file1 | uniq | wc -l)" -gt 1 ]]
    then
       echo "Date in file2 is greater than file1"
    else
       echo "Date in file2 is not greater than file1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'/' '{ d=$3$1$2 }
           NR==FNR{ t=d; nextfile }
           d > t{ 
               print "file2 has date(s) greater than in file1";
               exit 
           }' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
file2 has date(s) greater than in file1
```

Comment: That's not my vote.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this does require leading zeroes on both the day and month number. They could be added with `sprintf()` if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Get the time in seconds from epoch (see man stat) and print the difference.

```
T1=$(stat --printf='%Y\n' file1.txt)
T2=$(stat --printf='%Y\n' file2.txt)

echo $(($T1 - $T2))
```

Comment: I think they meant they have files that contain lists of dates. Not that they wanted to handle the timestamps of the files themselves